# Exclude 1 or more column in Impala

Tags: hadoop, impala

can I exclude 1 or more column in Impala without specifying all the columns in table

`SELECT * [except columnA] FROM tableA`

Comment: :) nope. no database system give you this ability.

Comment: @KoushikRoy was able to do this in Hive by using
"set hive.support.quoted.identifiers=none;"

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Why not create a view of the data without ColumnA?  Then you can just keep using the data but not have to have the column included?  It would require you to list all the Columns once, but after that you would be good to go.